# Select 10 images from MNIST dataset

Tags: python, mnist

I have to select a batch of 10 images from mnist dataset. Each image shall belong to one different class, i.e. image 0 to class 0, image 1 to class 1 etc.

I know that in the following way I extract all the dataset. I wonder how create a dataset of 10 images, each one belonging to a different class

```
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the unique method, from which I  sorted unique elements of an array and their index

```
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
train_filter = np.unique(Y_train, return_index=True)
X_train, Y_train = X_train[train_filter[1:]], Y_train[train_filter[1:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need 10, an easy way is to take the first 10 non-duplicated entries:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

ix = ~pd.Series(Y_train).duplicated()
X_10 = X_train[ix]
Y_10 = Y_train[ix]

Y_10
array([5, 0, 4, 1, 9, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8], dtype=uint8)
```